# XML file is unmodifiable, running on Ipad

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

My xml file is working fine in unity but when I run on ipad using Xcode . xml file doesn't modify but readable . xml file is in resource folder saving data by using

```
xml.Save(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(textXML));
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify files that are resources. Think of them as read only. You can save files in your app folder and you can get the path to that folder using

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

You should use this folder to save the XML file.

Comment: I am unable to get persistentDataPath :(

Comment: I was wrong writing ProductName with space ,attached with bundleIdentifier to get persistentdatapath :) thank you @hades2510